# Is it possible to use styled-theming to customize style-related props?

Tags: react-native, styled-components, activity-indicator

I'm using React-Native and i want to change the color prop of an ActivityIndicator according to the defined theme style. Is it possible do some like that using styled-theming? In ActivityIndicator, color is not set via 'style'.

eg:

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled, {ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components';
import theme from 'styled-theming';

// This works
const backgroundColor = theme('mode', {
  light: '#fff',
  dark: '#000',
});

const StyledView = styled.View`
    background-color: ${backgroundColor};
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
`;

// This not works
const sampleColor = theme('mode', {
  light: '#000',
  dark: '#fff',
});

const StyledActivityIndicator = styled.ActivityIndicator.attrs(props => ({
    color: ??? // how can i use sampleColor here?
})) ``

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={{ mode: 'dark' }}>
      <StyledView>
          <StyledActivityIndicator></StyledActivityIndicator>
      </StyledView>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

If I use a color code directly works, but I would like to use the defined variants, is it possible?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the solution:

```js
const sampleColor = theme('mode', {
    light: '#000',
    dark: '#fff',
});

const StyledActivityIndicator = styled.ActivityIndicator.attrs(props => ({
    color: sampleColor(props)
}))
```